# "Client network socket disconnected before secure TLS connection was established" on axios request (NextJS)

Tags: javascript, networking, next.js, axios

in my NextJS project on the **production environment**, there's a page with an axios request on the `getServerSideProps` function:

`let photoUrl = null;  try { photoUrl = await getImageUrl(parameter) } catch (e) {console.log(e)}`.

`getImageUrl` is an imported function that has an axios request inside of it. the request path is correct, we've checked multiple times. the function also makes use of an env variable, which is accessible to it.

However, upon opening the page and triggering the `getImageUrl` function, I catch an error:

- code
  :
  "ECONNRESET"
- headers
  :
  Accept
  :
  "application/json, text/plain, */*"
  Accept-Encoding
  :
  "gzip, deflate, br"
  Content-Length
  :
  "78"
  Content-Type
  :
  "application/json"
  User-Agent
  :
  "axios/1.1.3"
- message
  :
  "Client network socket disconnected before secure TLS connection was established"

I am very confused. perhaps the error is related to the TLS version of axios? Or related to the virtual private network my web app's in?

Assistance will be greatly appreciated :)